# segue.destinationviewcontroller is not what expecting why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I tried creating a segue in my project, the segue is working perfectly, but when I tried setting the value of some property it gives me an error.

```
unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x13fe42550
```

After some debugging I found that

```
segue.destinationViewController
```

is a `UIViewController` instead of my own controller class (`MyClass`)

I tried the following:

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]) {
    MyClass *mainViewConroller = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSInteger tagIndex = [(UILabel *)sender tag];
    mainViewConroller.id = @"65";
}
```

However, it's not returning an instance of the expected class name set in the class section of IB.

[image]

Comment: what is id in the mainViewController ? A string or a number ?

Comment: I suggest you not to use the name id as it conflicts with the datatype id. Use different variable names.

Comment: Also you are not using the variable tagIndex. What is the use of it ?

Comment: yes id is of type NSString and i tried different name also, but it won't work

Comment: main issue is segue.destinationViewController is not of type MyClass.

I guess i missed something thats why it is unable to resolve.

Comment: put a breakpoint and see where it crashes.

Comment: you can change the line to (MyClass *)segue.destinationViewController;

Comment: Did you set the Class in interface builder?

Comment: no still no success.

Comment: @Jan Greve no i don't. Please tell me how to do this. I think this is what i missed

Comment: @JanGreve it ain't give me option to select class

Comment: enable the exception breakpoint, and see where it hits when crash happened

Comment: "However, it's not returning an instance of the expected class name set in the class section of IB." Your screenshot show the class/settings of the segue, not of the ViewController.

Comment: Update your error message to show **what** selector is sent to **which** class?

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14800d240'

Comment: Have you set the class of the destination view controller (**not** the segue!) to your custom class in Interface Builder as asked in other comments? Select the view controller in IB and press ⌥⌘3.

Comment: @vadian yes it is set.

Comment: Actually the error message says it is not set otherwise the custom class is supposed to be the receiver. And there is a property (not just an instance variable) `id` in the destination view controller?

Comment: @vadian yes you are right i just checked i set class for the first view controller but not for the second. now its working.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to distinguish multiple segues is the identifier

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"reviewDetail"]) {
    MyClass *mainViewController = (MyClass *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSInteger tagIndex = [(UILabel *)sender tag];
    mainViewController.id = @"65";
}
```

Comment: got my issue. I forgot to set the controller class for second view controller.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem despite having the custom class set for the destination view controller. The problem was that I had "Module" set. I had spent several hours trying to figure out the problem and I did. I saw that my first view controller does not have anything in this field. As soon as I have deleted the value at the destination controller, the problem was fixed.

Comment: Huzzah! No idea how my controller lost its "Inherit module from target", but sure enough that was the reason I couldn't cast `segue.destinationController` to my custom VC class.

Answer (score 0):

segue.destinationViewController may in fact be your class-- you should first tag the segue with an identifier.  Second, check that the identifier is correct.  Third, cast the segue.destinationViewController to your class, as such:

`MyClass *vc = (MyClass *)segue.destinationViewController`

Then you can pass all the information you want.

Comment: Casting is just giving information to the compiler, it doesn't change what class your controller is at runtime

Comment: @AMayes I did all this.
Please check the image attached, it wont give me option to select the class.

Is this the issue?

Comment: @RatneshKumar The segue is supposed to be `UIStoryboardSegue`. Don't change that class.

Comment: You're not changing the segue's class, you're setting the class of your viewController in the storyboard.  segue.destinationViewController will always appear to be a UIViewController, but that is just the base class.  If the VC's class is set in storyboard, you just need to let the compiler know what that VC's class actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem, the class property in `UIStoryboardSegue` is there to allow you to set the class for that segue, that way you can customise your transitions and do some fancy stuff.

If you want a new class for the view controller you have to set it to the view controller at the end of the arrow of the segue.